# Проверка сертификата HTTPS

Tags: java, https

Есть сайт с поддержкой HTTPS и есть java программа. Необходимо с программы передавать информацию на сайт. 
Реализовал передачу все работает нормально, вот только как реализовать проверку сертификата?

```html
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 120000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 120000);

SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

sslctx.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] { new TrustManager() }, null);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslctx.getSocketFactory());
URL url = new URL(HTTPS + host + ":" + port + getPath());
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);

con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", base64.toString());
con.setRequestProperty("Host", host + ":" + port);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", getAcceptCharset());
con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", getContentType());

HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
 @Override
 public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
  return s.equals(sslSession.getPeerHost());
 }
};

con.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

if (getData() != null) {
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());

    ps.println(new String(getData().getBytes(), ENCODING_UTF));
    ps.close();
}

con.connect();

if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder resultData = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      resultData.append(line);
 }
    br.close();
}

con.disconnect();
```

```html
public class TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
 public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
 }

 public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
  
 }

 public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
  return new X509Certificate[0];
 }
}
```

Comment: Каким образом реализовано взаимодействие с HTTP/https сервером ?

Comment: Нужно какимто образом проверить сертификат, и сообщить пользователю результат, но при этом все равно отправить данные. Как обойти проверку я знаю, а вот как проверить?

Comment: Посмотрите код по нижнему ответу на вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528328/get-certificate-and-add-it-to-a-java-truststore-when-only-having-https-url
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#checkValidity()
http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/

Проверка на каком уровне нужна? Просто действителен ли сертификат на указанную дату? или полностью - с цепочкой из удостоверяющего центра?

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать полную проверку подлинности. Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я понимаю алгоритм. 1) Отправляю запрос на сервер.

Comment: 2) Из ответа получаю сертификат. 3) Сертификат нужно сохранить в хранилище, а потом каждый раз получать его и выполнять валидацию? либо 3) Полученый сертификат сразу проверить?

Comment: 3. по идее сохранять в хранилище не нужно. Т.к. сертификат на той стороне может в любой момент поменяться. Т.е. его нужно сразу после получения валидировать

Comment: С этим разобрался спасибо. Такой вопрос, а в случае самоподписанного сертификата при изменении его нужно каждый раз вручную добавлять в keystore? 
То есть если через месяц сертификат поменялся, что должна делать программа. Просто вывести сообщение и ждать добавления нового сертификата или можно программно обновить сертификат?

Comment: Я думаю, что в зависимости от задачи. Если Вы уверены, что никто не скомпрометирует сертификат - можно автоматически принимать. Насчет добавление в keystore не компетентен - зачем?

Comment: А вообще при изменении сертификата в любом случае стоит сообщать об этом пользователю.